# Can't add user to couchDB via angular but works with postman

Tags: json, angularjs, couchdb

**EDIT: The reason for this was because in couchDB config under cors, PUT was not enabled. After I enabled this it worked as it should!**

I am trying to add a new user to couchDB and it will work fine with postman for an example

I set the headers using admin username and password and then send the following

http://vps.xxxxxxxxx:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:test

With the following JSON

```
{"name":"dfbfdb","password":"fbdbfd","roles":[],"type":"user"}
```

And I get back

```
{"ok":true,"id":"org.couchdb.user:test","rev":"1-a9925d62c9529ab695ef0e7ff98e9965"}
```

However when trying to do the same in agular I keep just getting

```
OPTIONS http://vps.xxxxxx:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:test2 
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://vps.xxxxxx:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:test2. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

The controller I have built to do this is below.

```
app.controller('signUpController', ['UserService', '$http', '$location',
    function(UserService, $http, $location) {
        this.user = {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        }
        this.register = function() {
            var user = {
                name: this.user.username,
                password: this.user.password,
                roles: [],
                type: 'user'
            }
            console.log(user)
            $http({
                url: "http://vps.xxxxxxx:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:" + user.name,
                method: 'PUT',
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': auth_hash('adminname', 'adminpass')
                },
                data: user
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('user added')
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(angular.toJson(user))
                console.log(status)
                console.log(headers)
                console.log(config)
            })
        }
    }
]);
```

Does anyone have any idea why it will not work doing it through angular?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CouchDB config e.g

```
http://localhost:5984/_utils/config.html
```

Make sure the 'PUT' method is available to use in CORS.

Because I was updating the database over a different domain this is the reason I was getting a 405 error.